# What is the reason for receiving the exception code SEH 3221225501, which corresponds to the SEH exception STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tesseract, vcpkg

When starting the program after calling a function from the library tesseract41.dll my program was terminating execution by throwing an SEH exception on some computers. It turned out to intercept the exception code: 3221225501 (`C000001D` hex), which corresponds to the SEH exception STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION. I was building the tesseract library using vcpkg. What could be the problem? Are there types of processors that do not support this library build? I did not find in the vkpg documentation an opportunity to change the type of supported processor.

Comment: Possibly the library was compiled with CPU instructions that are not available on your platform.

Comment: I’ve had this happen. The person was using an extremely old cpu. The problem in your case you will have to find the instruction and investigate

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to tesseract v5.x - there is implemented runtime detection of simd availability

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips, I think the installation of Tesseract v5.x is the best solution, but I managed to solve the problem by getting version 4.1.1 using "vcpkg install tesseract[cpu-independed]:x64-windows". This version solves the problem of supporting legacy processors when compiling the library using vcpkg. Apparently, my version required the processor to support the AVX2 instruction set.